# Android BLE Device Button press Alert in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with BLE device.I perform the code using [android GATT](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#notification) and it scan device and also I send immediate alert in BLE device from mobile using writeCharacteristic and BLE device is beep.But now I want to Alert in android Mobile when I press BLE device button. That exactly I don't know how to do.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to listen for characteristics change. When you will press the BLE button, a characteristics must be change inside its hardware (set any flag value depends on hardware's firmware coding). When characteristics changed, characteristics method will called. You can perform required functionality there.

```
 @Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic 
                                                             characteristic) 
    {


     Here we received ble button pressed event callback. Do stuff here.

 }
```

For receiving characteristics change callback first you have to enable the notification like this.

```
          BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(mServiceUuuid).getCharacteristic(mCharOneUuuid);
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            List<BluetoothGattDescriptor> list = characteristic.getDescriptors();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = list.get(i);
                desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                gatt.writeDescriptor(desc);
            }
```